# set attribute with polyline points

Tags: javascript

I know that the following code would be set out in this particular way to say set attribute of a rectangles width is it the same for a polyline or do you have to change it ?

```
function newer() {
        document.getElementById("rectangle").setAttribute('width',"70");
}
```

Would it by like the follwoing code for a polyline or would it be some other way?

```
  function new() {
        document.getElementById("polyline1").setAttribute('points', "0,0 200,0 200,200 100,200 100,100 0,100 0,0" );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about SVG polylines (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polyline.asp) then points is an attribute and "0,0 200,0 200,200 100,200 100,100 0,100 0,0" is the atttirbute value.

So yes.